# Concatination of strings in Swift

Tags: ios, string, swift

I would like to get final String like below:

```
var urlString = "http://testurl.com/contacts=["1111111","2222222"]"
```

There are three strings `http://testurl.com/contacts=` , `1111111` and `2222222`

How to concatenate these strings in Swift

Answer (score 0):

```
var str1 =  "http://testurl.com/contacts="
var str2 = "1111111"
var str3 = "2222222"
var finalString = "\(str1)[\"\(str2)\",\"\(str3)\"]"
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting like this http://testurl.com/contacts=[\"1111111\",\"2222222\"]

Comment: see the pic attached with the answer.